# How do I enable ctfmon.exe under Windows 7 Professional

Tags: windows, configuration, installation

Not sure if this is the right forum, but here it goes....

*Problem Description in Brief:*
I am not able to enable `ctfmon.exe` to execute (and to remain running) on Startup under Windows 7 Professional (SP1).  I need this for the language bar on the taskbar, and the ability to switch between Chinese and English.

*Problem Description in Detail*:
When I installed Windows 7 Professional on my ASUS laptop, I enabled the language bar so that I can switch between Chinese and English, with the default language being Chinese (for my wife).  Everything worked fine, even after installing Microsoft Office 2010, which apparently relies on `ctfmon.exe` for the language bar services.  When I uninstalled Microsoft Office, not only did I lose the language bar, but the ability to switch between Chinese and English.  The only language supported now on Startup is Chinese.

Needless to say that the option to enable `ctfmon` is not available under the Starup tab of `msconfig`.  In order to enable the language bar, again, I have to manually change it via the Control Panel, only to lose it, *again*, every second time I shutdown and/or restart the laptop!!!  It is @#$%ing annoying to say the least!!!

Note that, the language bar driver (`ctfmon.exe`) still resides in the `C:\Windows\System32\` directory according to many of the forums I have read.  I have even added a Windows registry entry to execute it at Startup according to one of the posts in the Microsoft TechNet site, titled [Language Bar Disappeared](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/b4441951-1b0d-4e4c-b133-9f9cb08fefc9/language-bar-disappeared?forum=itprovistadesktopui), and another UK site titled [Startup Details - ctfmon.exe](http://www.pacs-portal.co.uk/startup_pages/12000-12999/12195_ctfmon.exe.htm), which believes the entry should exist under HKCU as opposed to HKLM.  Specifically, I added the following entries to the Windows Registry File without any effect.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
"ctfmon"="C:\Windows\System32\ctfmon.exe"
```

and,

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
"ctfmon"="C:\Windows\System32\ctfmon.exe"
```

Since `msimtf.dll` and `msctf.dll` are related to the language bar service, I tried enabling those using `regsvr32`.  Although they were successfully loaded, it did not have any effect on the language bar.  I even tried to execute `ctfmon.exe` at the command prompt!  It still did not activate the language bar like it is supposed to according to many of the forums I visited relating to this problem.

Short of reinstalling Microsoft Office and/or reinstalling Windows 7 Professional, any advise/suggestions on how to resolve this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: I have the exactly same problem, that's so annoying!

Answer (score 5):

Follow the instructions below to run `ctfmon` automatically on Windows startup process.

1. Click Windows 7 start button.
2. Type: regedit
3. Open it with administrative rights.
4. Goto `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`
5. Create a new string value
6. Name it as you wish
7. Open it for edit
8. Type `“ctfmon”=”CTFMON.EXE”` in Value data field
9. Press OK
10. Restart your computer

Now you can see the language bar :)

Comment: Thanks Ahmed but I eventually solved the problem by reinstalling Windows 7 Professional for other reasons....

Answer (score -2):

Do not worry. You may try this step.

Press Windows along with R ( Windows + R ) and then run box will appear then type the path on the run box..

C:\Windows\System32\ctfmon.exe

Then press enter.

Comment: Obviously, you have not read the question in more detail part, where I specifically state that running ctfmon.exe at the command prompt has no effect.  Nevertheless, I resolved the problem by reinstalling Windows 7 Professional for other reasons....